# Hadoop : There are 1 datanode(s) running and 1 node(s) are excluded in this operation

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs

We are running Hadoop on another machine in the same network cable to put files in Hadoop from the same system but when the application is trying to put the file in Hadoop getting the following error.

Hadoop setup is a single node setup.

Getting error with  Hadoop

```
Fetching value from cache - key: 254af6643e1bf515123de68e6ea6b3256e0b9f11
Found file import entry for datasetId: 254af6643e1bf515123de68e6ea6b3256e0b9f11
21/09/12 09:55:52 WARN DataStreamer: Abandoning BP-452841745-127.0.0.1-1631439723175:blk_1073741825_1001
21/09/12 09:55:52 WARN DataStreamer: Excluding datanode DatanodeInfoWithStorage[127.0.0.1:9866,DS-2b79652d-f07c-4924-a901-7f38141af2b5,DISK]
21/09/12 09:55:52 WARN DataStreamer: DataStreamer Exception
org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(java.io.IOException): File /user/test/uploadedDatasets/254af6643e1bf515123de68e6ea6b3256e0b9f11/_temporary/0/_
temporary/attempt_20210912095551948982914863741166_0023_m_000000_0/part-00000 
could only be written to 0 of the 1 minReplication nodes. There are 1 datanode(s) running and 1 node(s) are excluded in this operation
```

Running

./start-dfs.sh

Running JPS

```
1747400 DataNode
1747647 SecondaryNameNode
1763807 Jps
1747191 NameNode
```

Comment: From the namenode UI, are you able to see the connected datanodes? Are these any exceptions in the logs for either of those datanode/namenode process before you try to copy files?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.